# docker cockpit error after redirecting with nginx

Tags: proxy, docker

Distro: Arch Linux,
service app: systemctl,
(cockpit is a web based system administration and docker container manager).

I recently installed cockpit on a VPS and is working great on IP:9090,
later i figured out that it serves connection from localhost as http but when connected from remote it uses https with a randomly generated ssl, i wanted to serve it on a subdomain like cockpit.domain.com. So i did it by nginx using a proxy virtual block, it worked good.

But after i login, it says 'Server has closed the connection.'

How to configure cockpit to serve remote connections on a proxy?

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    www.cockpit.domain.com cockpit.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.cockpit.domain.com cockpit.domain.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems fine. What is in your logs?

Comment: nginx is working good, thats not the issue. i believe cockpit is refusing connections. i cheched out cockpit.service but could not understand the config.

Comment: here is the nginx access log http://pastebin.com/cQDi9V6F and error log is empty

Answer (score 1):

cockpit uses websocket to push active data like memory, cpu, swap, storage usage back and forth between server and client but when a proxy sits in between, it has to be configured likely.

To configure Cockpit proxy over NGINX, create a server virtual block, and add the following lines to it. This config would deliver specific set of work environments. Do change config to your custom needs.

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
    server 127.0.0.1:9090;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cockpit.domain.tld www.cockpit.domain.tld;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.cockpit.domain.tld cockpit.domain.tld;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        # needed for websocket
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        # change scheme of "Origin" to http
        proxy_set_header Origin http://$host;
    }

}
```

By default Cockpit uses http protocol to connect to localhost, Since our proxy would likely reside on localhost we would redirect all http client requests to https return `301 https://$server_name$request_uri`

By default cockpit generates a ssl certificate which is stored at /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/. In our case we would used NGINX to do all the TLS encryption work. Edit these lines with your own ssl server and client keys. ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate; ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;
(You can also use the certificate stored at /etc/ws-certs.d/)
This would enable us to redirect to Cockpit via this proxy host.

Comment: This answer and question seem literally copy and pasted. Also, the formatting is horrible.